# How do you rotate the Raspberry Pi touchscreen on Kali?

Tags: pi-2, touchscreen, kali

So I have the 7" Raspberry Pi touchscreen and on Raspbian I used the command `sudo nano /boot/config.txt` and I would add the line `lcd_rotate=2` and this would flip the display, I have booted Kali on to my SD card now and I try to run the same commands, but this does not flip the display, and neither does `display_rotate=2`. Does anyone know how I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to mount /boot first using `mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot` You can then go in to the config.txt file using `sudo nano /boot/config.txt` and add the line `lcd_rotate=2`. ctrl+x, y, Enter, and then `reboot`.